# PlaygroundBook liveView display a SceneView error

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, swift-playground

I am currently playing with PlaygroundBook. From the Doc, it says that you can use LiveView.swift to present a always-on View in the liveView. So I create a SceneViewController in the Source Folder. In the SceneViewController, I create a Sphere which lightingModel is **physicallyBased**, and I using a 3D map as the background contents.

Then in the LiveView.swift

```
import PlaygroundSupport
let page = PlaygroundPage.current
page.current.liveView = SceneViewController()
```

**But** when I run it in the iPad Air Playground. I get no error, but the liveView didn't show anything!

I spend many years finding errors. And I have try to create a new iOS Project using the same SceneViewController, and it work very well. I got no idea.

In the last, I try to change the lightingModel to .phong, and change the background to the white color.

**Then the magic thing happened! The liveView now show a black sphere and the white background.**

**Why?**

From the WWDC Session, I learn that I can use proxy to communicate with main process in Contents.swift and LiveView process.

So next, I make a extension.

```
extension SceneViewController: PlaygroundLiveViewMessageHandler {
    public func receive(_ message: PlaygroundValue) {
        if case let .string(_) = message {
            changeColor()
        }
    }
}
```

And inside the Contents.swift, I create a new function

```
func addSky() {
    if let proxy = page.liveView as? PlaygroundRemoteLiveViewProxy {
        proxy.send(.string("addSky"))
    }
}
```

And everyTime I call it, The liveView **changed**, see the image below. It's the same as The first time I try to use a 3D map as the background.
[image]

**Does anyone know what does it happened ?**